# How get average value fro each columns from pivot pandas python?

Tags: python, pandas

i have use pandas python to analze my data, and i have result from pivot pandas like :

`namevendors          A           B                C
unique_id

46                   4           0                0

58                   2           0                0

362                  1           0                0

545                  2           0                0

638                  2           0                0

745                  2           0                0

1014                 2           0                0

1114                 4           0                0

1254                 1           0                0

1354                 1           0                0

2089                 4           0                0

2472                 4           1                0

2949                 2           0                0

3049                 1           0                1`

and i need to get average value from each name vendors, i want result like :

`name vendors A B C
[2.2857142857142856 0.07142857142857142 0.07142857142857142]`

how can i do that ? name vendors can be more than three

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.mean().to_frame().T
```

Produces:

```
namevendors         A         B         C
0            2.285714  0.071429  0.071429
```

Comment: Hi @Jarad 
```
df = pd.DataFrame(datas, columns=['unique_id', 'namevendors', 'count'])
  
pt = df.pivot(index='unique_id', columns='namevendors', values='count').fillna(0)
```

and use your solution, still can't done

Comment: Not clear what you mean. The data in your original question as of right now is formatted oddly (gray line every other row) I'm assuming it is a single dataframe named `df`. If you have it named something else, use that name, and append `.mean().to_frame().T`. If it's not working, then communicate what's not working or no one can help you.